# Count Array where Column Value Equals Given

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I have a controller where an array of checkbox values are passed on to the controller and then sent on to do a variety of tasks. My problem is focused on getting a count of the arrays' shipment's customer's billing method, but I'm not entirely sure how I would get those values since I'm posting an array and I want a count.

Here's my controller:

```
public function sendNow(Request $request)
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $sendNowShipment = array();
        $method = array();
        $sendNowShipment = request('send');
            foreach($sendNowShipment as $SNS){
                $shipment = Shipment::findOrFail($SNS);
                if($shipment->billtoAccount->billingMethods->label == "Mail"){
                $timestamp = Carbon::now()->timestamp;
                $shipment_details = $shipment->shipment_details;
                    $path = 'temp/freightbill_'.$shipment->pro_number.'-'.$timestamp.'.pdf';
                    $sessionPath[] = $path;
                    $pdf = PDF::loadView('shipments.pdf', compact('shipment', 'shipment_details'))
                        ->save($path);
                }elseif($shipment->billtoAccount->billingMethods->label == "Email"){
                    $billToAccount =   $shipment->billtoAccount;
                    $billToAccountUsers = $billToAccount->users;
                        if ($billToAccount->primary_email){
                            $billToEmail[] = $billToAccount->primary_email;
                        }
                        if ($billToAccountUsers->count() > 0){
                            foreach ($billToAccountUsers as $billToAccountUser){
                                $billToEmail[] = $billToAccountUser->email;
                            }
                        }
                        foreach ($billToEmail as $bte){
                            Mail::to($bte)->send(new newBillToShipment($shipment));
                        }
                }
            }

        if(count($shipment->billtoAccount->billingMethods->label == "Mail") > 0){// count where shipments->customers->billingMethods = Mail) > 0
            $pdf = new PDFMerger();

            // Add 2 PDFs to the final PDF
            foreach($sessionPath as $sp){
            $pdf->addPDF($sp, 'all');
            }

            // Merge the files and retrieve its PDF binary content
            $timestamp = Carbon::now()->timestamp;
            $binaryContent = $pdf->merge('download', $timestamp."-printBatch.pdf");

            // Return binary content as response
            //return response($binaryContent)
              //  ->header('Content-type' , 'application/pdf');
            return back();
            //dd($sendNowShipment,$sendMethod);
    }
    }
```

If you look at this line (a little past the middle):

```
if(count($shipment->billtoAccount->billingMethods->label == "Mail") > 0){
// count where shipments->customers->billingMethods = Mail) > 0
```

You'll see that I'm going through a multitude of relationships just to get the value of "Mail" that I am looking for.

So I'm wondering if this should be a DB:: query through laravel, but I'm not sure how I would perform the query using the given checkbox array I have being POSTed to this controller.

Comment: Off the top of my head, rather than counting them all, you could just grab the first that matched: `$shipment->billtoAccount->billingMethods->where('label' ,'=', 'Mail')->first()`  to return true if one is found.  This is the method I tend to use when checking for a checkbox value. There may be a faster/more optimal way, but if there is, I don't know it.